# Shouldn't the blog offer the possibility of e-mail subscription?

Tags: feature-request, blog

The only subscription method is via RSS.

Answer (score 3):

When the blog is actually back up and running actively, I will see about that as an option. I plan a great many improvements but at the moment I'm job hunting and I don't have anyone helping me with the blog as my co-runner has become less active due to school.